# PDO fetch returns not all rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this SQL/PHP code:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmtCLN=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM historie WHERE cn_id=:cid");
$stmtCLN->bindParam(':cid', $id);
$stmtCLN->execute();
$rowCLN = $stmtCLN->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

The Problem is, that it not returns all rows.What can it be?

```
<?  foreach($stmtCLN as $rowCLN) { ?>
<? echo $rowCLN[2]; ?>
...
...
<? } ?>
```

Comment: using the wrong function and not looping over results

Comment: Please consider giving us more information about how many rows you have and what is being returned. Are you missing one row out of five? One of two? These can help us determine the issue far more easily.

Comment: In most cases I miss one row.

Comment: You need a while loop `while($rowCLN = $stmtCLN->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) { ... do something with row ... }`

Comment: To answer your question: [read this in PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Answer (score 0):

The PDO fetch function returns either one or zero rows.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

The code you show would fetch, at most, one row. This behavior is documented. It's not a problem.

If fetch doesn't return a row, because there are no more rows to be fetched, the function returns FALSE.

If your code needs to fetch another row, then then call the `fetch` function again.

If you want to return all the rows in one fell swoop, instead of fetching one row at a time, you might want to consider using the PDO `fetchAll` function.

Comment: Sorry my fault. Here ist the code how I fetch through the rows (see my first post)

Comment: OK, until now I don't figured out what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me please? If I do it with fetchAll it returns nothing.

Comment: Thank you guy. Now it works. I try it with  "while($rowCLN = $stmtCLN->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {"